# Drupal Commerce 2CheckOut module - Step by step integration/configuration?

Tags: drupal-7

Using drupal I just want one time checkout functionality to be integrated. I have see Commerce 2CheckOut module which integrate 2checkout gateway. Is it possible to get steps to integrate/configyre this module in our website?

Answer (score 0):

I recently fixed a bunch of things in this module and opened an issue to get the changes added. If you still need them, the step by step instructions and the fixed module can be found at [this URL](https://github.com/craigchristenson/drupal-commerce-2checkout)